# \r\n characters in CSV file not treated as line breaks

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, export-to-csv, line-breaks

Apologies for what is surely a bonehead question...
I am trying to create a CSV file that looks like this:

`Header1,Header2,Header3,
"Value1","Value2","Value3"`

Instead, I'm getting a CSV file that looks like this:
`Header1,Header2,Header3,\r\n"Value1","Value2","Value3"`

**How do I get my CRLF characters to actually produce line breaks in my output?**

What I'm doing is making an ajax call to a WebMethod that generates a datatable from a stored proc. That datatable is then parsed out to a CSV like so:

```
if (!createHeaders)//I deal with the headers elsewhere in the code
{
    foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns){

        result += col.ColumnName + ",";
    };
    result += Environment.NewLine;
}

for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < table.Rows.Count; rowNum++) 
{
    for (int colNum = 0; colNum < table.Columns.Count; colNum++)
    {
        result += "\"" + (table.Rows[rowNum][colNum]).ToString();
        result += "\",";
    };
    result += Environment.NewLine;
};
return result;
}
```

That string is then passed back to the success function of the ajax query, where it undergoes a few more transformations...

```
function getExportFile(sType) {
    var alertType = null
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",      
        url: "./Services/DataLookups.asmx/getExcelExport",
        data: JSON.stringify({ sType: sType }),
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (response) {                
            response = replaceAll(response,"\\\"", "\"")
            response = response.replace("{\"d\":\"", "")
            response = response.replace("\"}", "")
            download(sType + ".csv",response)
        }
    });

    function download(filename, text) {
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
        element.setAttribute('download', filename);
        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click()
        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }

    function escapeRegExp(str) {
        return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    }

    function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
        return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
    }
```

In my debugging before the string is passed back to javascript, if I just type ?response, I get the incorrect, all-on-one-line response. However, when I type ?resonse,nq the linebreaks are recognized, and everything looks the way it should.

Also, I'm sure there is PLENTY that I'm doing wrong/stupidly here. Pointing out those instances is also appreciated.

Comment: Are u seeing `\r\n` in the debugger or in the output file ?

Comment: both. they go away in the debugger when I request "?response,nq", but are present when I request "?response"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header should have `data:Application/octet-stream,` as MIME-type instead of `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,`, the reason being that as per HTTP specifications, when the content type is unknown, the recipient should treat it as type application/octet-stream.

Since you are already using the `encodeURIComponent()`, that seems to be the only issue remaining.

Answer (score 1):

@AryKay's answer surely helped, but there was one additional issue.  The string returned by the Ajax call had the`\r\n`s escaped into literals.  Ran a

`Response = response.replace (/\\r\\n/g, "\r\n")`

Before passing to `encodeURIComponent` and it ran like a charm.