# Dataprep flow from csv in Cloud Storage to Big Query table incomplete (not all records loaded)

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataprep

I set up a **Dataprep scheduled job** flow copying and treating daily some **csv** and **json** files stored in a **Cloud Storage bucket** **to Big Query tables**. 
It was working fine, but since some days the job started copying in Big Query less rows than those contained in the csv and json files.
I don't know if this is related but in the same time the process upstream changed also the content type of the files.
The csvs switched from **application/octet-stream** to **text/csv; charset=utf-8**.
The jsons from **application/json** to **application/json; charset=utf-8**.
Can this change of content type be somehow related?
Otherwise does anybody had some similar issues?

I created the same version of csv file (with 5 records) one with content type 
**application/octet-stream** the other **text/csv; charset=utf-8**. Then I created a simple Dataprep job just reading the csv files and converting some integer variable to test and exporting the end result to a Big Query table.

The flow treating the csv with **application/octet-stream** encoding exported 5 records to Big Query, as expected. The one treating the csv with **text/csv; charset=utf-8**, exported only 3 records, even if the data recipe in the Dataprep Transformer node shown 5 records.

Find here below my target Big Query schema:

CustomerID:STRING,
CustomerUniqueRef:STRING,
BranchID:STRING,
DateCreated:DATETIME,
CreatedBy:STRING,
PreviouslyBanked:STRING

My transformations in Dataprep are just converting CustomerID, CustomerUniqueRef, CreatedBy and PreviouslyBanked from INTEGER to STRING.

Find also my csv for test:

CustomerID,CustomerUniqueRef,BranchID,DateCreated,CreatedBy,PreviouslyBanked
43944,0004674956,004,2019-06-14T10:52:11,77,1
43945,0004674957,004,2019-06-14T10:59:32,77,0
43946,0004674958,004,2019-06-14T11:03:14,77,0
43947,0004674959,004,2019-06-14T11:06:23,77,0
43948,0004674960,004,2019-06-14T11:09:24,77,0

Comment: Hey Giorgio,  can you please attach your BQ table schema & an example of some records you are trying to insert?

Comment: Hi Royzipuff, sure, I just edited to add Big Query schema and csv sample.

Comment: Thanks, I have created a similar flow in Dataprep importing the CSV records you attached from GCS (as text/csv), and a corresponding table in BigQuery. 
All 5 rows seem to load successfully. Does your Dataprep job append / truncate / drop-create the destination table every time you run it?

Comment: Thanks! My Dataprep job creates a new Big Query table every time I run it. Like prefix_20190616_161227. That didn't change anyway.

Comment: @Royzipuff text/csv; charset=utf-8 and text/csv are the same?

Comment: Yes they are. CustomerUniqueRef values start with 000 and are identified as STRING in Dataprep automatically (so I didn't have to transfer them to STRING as you mentioned, that's the only difference I see between our jobs)

Try creating a new flow, with a new recipe that converts only CustomerID, CreatedBy, PreviouslyBanked from INTEGER to STRING

Comment: I wrote it wrong, as you said CustomerUniqueRef was already STRING. So I'm kind of puzzled, I still can't get the good output

Comment: Can you confirm your CSV file has a single header row with 6 columns and 5 rows of comma delimited data where each row is new-line delimited?

Comment: Yes 1 header row, 6 columns and 5 rows. When I open it with Notepad++ I see LF as end of line, I guess  it should be \n.

Comment: Yes, actually, you shouldn't see any special character at the end of lines. Make sure that the .CSV in GCS has proper break lines without any special characters (not LF nor \n)

Comment: sorry.. I should know better, how can I see what is the character that break lines in my csv?

Comment: \n = LF (Line Feed), moves the cursor down to the next line . In *nix environment, will move the cursor to the beginning of the line. Usually transparent, meaning you shouldn’t have it explicitly written in your file.

Comment: I suspect that somehow break-line characters are mistreated in the CSV. I say this because when I look at the Google Dataflow job behind DataPrep one, in the first node only 4 elements are inputted, while it should be five. So my guess is DataFlow (behind DataPrep) can't split properly 4th and 5th row and so it can't load it. Might be connected to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888534/r-n-characters-in-csv-file-not-treated-as-line-breaks

Comment: Hi Royzipuff, I finally found what the issue was. It was a matter of incorrect parametrization of the csv in Cloud Storage. Its content-type was text/csv; charset=utf-8 and content-encoding gzip. So actually the csv was compressed. Moving to content-type=text/csv and content-encoding=utf-8 solved the issue. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Giorgio, could you post this solution as an actual answer? Making it more visible can help to others.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found what the issue was. It was a matter of incorrect parametrization of the csv in Cloud Storage. Its content-type was text/csv; charset=utf-8 and content-encoding gzip. So actually the csv was compressed. Moving to content-type=text/csv and content-encoding=utf-8 solved the issue.